# Connect Qt to raspberry pi via ssh communication

Tags: c++, qt, ssh

I'm working on a simple game project between Qt and raspberry pi.

Does anyone have a tutorial or simple Qt code on how to establish communication between `Qt to Raspberry pi` via ssh communication?

I did some research about this issue but most of them requires library like "`libssh`" which i'm not quite familiar with.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, does the Qt toolkit implement an ssh client at all? If so, take a look at the documentation, I'd say.

Comment: there is no SSH functionality in Qt. you are likely to have to use libssh for that.

Comment: and how do i do it with libssh?

Comment: @KuroyukiHikari have you even looked at libssh? Try the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not include an SSH client or server, you would need to use another SSH library for this, for example [libssh2](https://www.libssh2.org/).

Alternatively, you could consider a couple of other ways:

Use a [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html)/[QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html) and an external ssh client (e.g the `ssh` command line tool) to tunnel the TCP connection.

Use a [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) to run the `ssh` command line tool to create the connection and read & write data over the terminal connection.

Use SSL instead of SSH by using the [QSslSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html).